# Can I set outlook to default to printing monthly

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, printing

When I select to print a calendar in Outlook 2007, it shows me Daily and Weekly but monthly is half hidden.

Can I make this the detault to save having to scroll down each time (or forgetting and printing 31 pages of daily!)

Answer (score 0):

I use 2003.

When I invoke the Print menu, I get a "Page setup" choice. Here I can set the print out to my desired default.